# Can you enumerate and call different subclass constructors through a for loop?

Tags: c++

If I have several subclasses of the same Base class that take the same type and amount of arguments in there constructors similar to:

```
class Base {};

Class A : public Base
{
    A(arg1, arg2){};
};

Class B : public Base
{
    B(arg1, arg2){};
};

Class C : public Base
{
    C(arg1, arg2){};
};
```

I am wondering if there is a clever way one could enumerate or alias them to have their constructor called for specific numbers in a loop. For example 1, 3 and 7 call A's constructor, 2 and 6 call B's and 4 and 5 call C's.

I am trying to avoid writing switch or if statements where the only difference is the class name.

Currently using something like:

```
int main() {

   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       switch(i)
       {
           case 1:
           case 2:
           case 7:
              A(/*args*/);
              break;
           case 2:
           case 6:
              B(/*args*/);
              break;
           case 4:
           case 5:
              C(/*args*/);
              break;
       };
   };
};
```

would like to have 1 expression to handle all instances since the arguments don't change. This is an over-simplified idea of what I am trying to do. I am using nested loops with multiple variables to instantiate and store many different objects in a container to be used later. The code is very long and identical save for the subclass constructor calls.

Is it possible to use the loop incrementor to create different subclasses or do I have to stick to using the long, repetitive method above?

Comment: This strikes me as an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the issue you hope to solve by doing this? A constructor call in C++ starts the lifetime of an object. It doesn't make sense to ephemerally create it, not use it, and let it destroy itself immediately after -- that seems like a job better suited to a function call at that point.

Comment: Where are those numbers coming from?  How are they mapped to the subclasses?

Comment: is the purpose of your question to find an efficient way to call functions / members in a given order? in your case `A, B, A, C, C, B, A`

Comment: The example doesn't show what I am doing with it. It is actually being assigned to a container to be used later. the example was just to give an idea of what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: the purpose is that the loop variable corresponds to a location on the grid and depending on the location it will create a specific type of object. the order is pretty chaotic and the example was just to show that different numbers could correspond to the same subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question at face-value seems to be a bit of an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/), since you mention that you are trying to create and store a large number of these in a container.

There is no way to simply call different instances of the derived constructors directly like you ask in your question, but there may be a better approach following a more SOLID architecture. From your description, it sounds like your problem would be better suited to using the [factory-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to create your objects, since you mention that the constructor signatures are all the same. You may even be able to use a class template to simplify this.

Following with your example of `A`, `B`, and `C`, and assuming that the args it takes are both `int`, you should be able to do something like:

```cpp
struct MyFactory {
    virtual ~MyFactory() = default;

    virtual auto make(int arg1, int arg2) -> std::unique_ptr<Base> = 0;
};

// T will be derived from 'Base' (e.g. 'A', 'B', or 'C')
template <typename T>
struct TFactory : public MyFactory {
    auto make(int arg1, int arg2) -> std::unique_ptr<Base> override {
        // Allocate and construct a derived instance
        return std::make_unique<T>(arg1, arg2);
    }
};
```

With this basic structure, you can use a data-structure that assigns the condition (the `int` counter of the loop) to the factory itself -- and then key off of this to create instances of your `Base` object. Without more concrete details its hard to say what your requirements are, but just as a simple example to transform your original code, we could do this with an associative container such as an [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map):

```cpp
// Map the 'int' to the factory itself
auto factories = std::unordered_map<int,std::unique_ptr<MyFactory>>{}

// Cases for A
factories[1] = std::make_unique<TFactory<A>>();
factories[2] = std::make_unique<TFactory<A>>();
factories[7] = std::make_unique<TFactory<A>>();

// Cases for B
factories[3] = std::make_unique<TFactory<B>>();
factories[6] = std::make_unique<TFactory<B>>();

// Cases for C
factories[4] = std::make_unique<TFactory<C>>();
factories[5] = std::make_unique<TFactory<C>>();
// etc
```

At which point, to populate your container, you can simply loop through and apply your condition(s):

```cpp
auto data = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>{};
for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   data.emplace_back( factories[i % 10]->make(...) );
}
```

This is, of course, just a high-level idea for how this can be accomplished. You might need tweaks for your specific case, since it's unclear what arguments your are passing, or how these map together. If you anticipate a lot of repeated cases for the same factories, you can use also be using `shared_ptr` instead to avoid the duplicate allocations -- but the idea is still the same.

Comment: This looks like a very nice way to go about it. Thank you.